# Gauss' Lemma and repeated factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I am reading a proof showing that $x^5+y^7 +z^{11}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$. We use the natural isomorphism to show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z] \cong \mathbb{C}[y,z][x]$.

We want to use Eisenstein's criterion to show that there exists $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[y,z]$ such that $p \mid y^7 + z^{11}$ and $p^2 \nmid y^7 + z^{11}$.

It makes sense that we want to do this. However, the proof goes on to say that it suffices to find such $p(x) \in k(z)[y]$ where $k(z)$, I'm assuming, is the field of fractions of polynomials in $z$ over $k$.

Since $y^7 + z^{11}$ is a non-unit over a UFD $k(z)[y]$ it is divisible by some irreducible $p(x) \in k(z)[y]$.

Furthermore, we can show that $y^7 + z^{11}$ has no repeated factors in $k(z)[y]$.

I think it is necessary to work in $k(z)[y]$ for the $gcd$ computation giving us that there are no repeated factors.

However, how does having no repeated factors in $k(z)[y]$ imply that there are no repeated factors in $k[z,y]$?

My notes say this is by Gauss' lemma. However, Gauss' lemma only tells me that if $R$ is UFD then $R[x]$ is UFD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $p(y,z)$ is a nonconstant factor of $y^7+z^{11}$ in $k[y,z]$, show that the degree of $y$ in $p(y,z)$ is positive.  This will show that $p(y,z)$ is nonconstant in $k(z)[y]$.  Hence, if $p(y,z)$ is a repeated nonconstant factor of $y^7+z^{11}$ in $k[y,z]$, then it is a repeated nonconstant factor of $y^7+z^{11}$ in $k(z)[y]$.

Comment: Are you using Gauss' lemma in this argument?

Comment: Don't see a reason to use it here, but sure, you can use it.

Comment: I don't fully see why being a repeated factor in $k[y,z]$ implies that it is a repeated factor in $k(z)[y]$. It's most likely trivial but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: If $p$ is a repeated factor in $k[y,z]$, then $p^2$ is a factor in $k[y,z]$, which then means that $p^2$ is a factor in $k(z)[y]$.  Hence, $p$ is a repeated factor in $k(z)[y]$.

Comment: Ok. I see where this is coming from now. Thank you!